# How To use Vue.js template in another HTML file

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have created a template using vue.js Now I want to use this template in another HTML file by using template Id

```
ex <div id="widgetId"> </div>
```

widgetId is the template Id

Here I am trying to create embed code for displaying the template

But I am not getting any result. Is there any way to get the Vue template in another html file when I use this embed code directly?

My code is given below

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'widget-pos';
div.id = 'widget-posId';
document.body.appendChild(div);

var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.id = 'widget-iframeId';
iframe.src = "javascript:false";
document.getElementById("widget-posId").appendChild(iframe);

document.getElementById('widget-iframeId').contentWindow.document.write(" 
<html><body><div id=widgetId></div></body></html>");

var iframeScript = document.createElement('script');
iframeScript.setAttribute("src","/packs/main.js");

var Vuescript = document.createElement('script');
Vuescript.setAttribute('src',"//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js")


$("#widget-iframeId").contents().find("head").append(iframeScript);
$("#widget-iframeId").contents().find("head").append(Vuescript);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to read this [article](https://sebastiandedeyne.com/dealing-with-templates-in-vue-20).

One solution could to import your external template like this:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  template: require('./myTemplate.html')
});
```